# how to Filter Search and concatunate 2 model results in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've big problem on making my page filtering search results as i get data from 2 Model,
the problem in second model that i need to get two paths in one select and concatunate with the result of first Model
Schedule Model:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone{ get; set; }
    public string Area{ get; set; }        
    [StringLength(255)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int ATMId { get; set; }
    public virtual ATM ATM { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
```

Picture Model :

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public bool IsAfterCleaning { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public virtual Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
```

And I need the result like that

schedId || DueDate ||Notes  || PathIsAfterCleaning || PathIsBeforeCleaning

i mean in one raw ?
second , can i make action result take 3 parameters like (Area , Id ,...)  pls any help

Answer (score 0):

I would create a model more specific to your view... in this case create a class

```
public class MyPageModel
{
    public Schedule MySchedule; 
    public Picture MyPicture; 
}
```

...

then pass your new composite model around to the views as needed.

Comment: with this class i can get all properties in the 2 model but how about the Result on (IsAfterCleaning) that represent 2 rows from second model as i get only one from the first model ?